# Check if membership exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.5 I am checking that a `profile->user->membership->id` is equal to `user->membership->id` like this:

```
if ($profile->user->membership->id != $user->membership->id ) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'error' => true,
            'status_code' => 400,
            'message' => 'profile_does_not_belong_to_membership',
        ));
    }
```

This works but if `profile->user->membership` does not exists then I get an error:

> trying to get property of a non-object error.

Do I need to check for this first or is there a way I can combine it with the original statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) helper:

```
optional($profile->user->membership)->id
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional):

> The `optional` function accepts any argument and allows you to access properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is `null`, properties and methods will return `null` instead of causing an error

Comment: Thanks for that, I was just reading up on optional when you replied!

Comment: Can you use optional multiple times?  So it won't break if profile does not have user either?

Comment: @fightstarr20 sure you can `optional(optional(profile->user)->membership)->id`

Comment: I'm getting unexpected -> error with multiple optionals

Comment: @fightstarr20 I've missed the `$` in the example. `optional(optional($profile->user)->membership)->id`. Just tested similar code, works fine.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, it's been a long day, thanks for the pointers!